# convert landscape image to portrait

Tags: printing, pdf, okular

I;m using the USPS app to generate a shipping label.  The app doesn't print the label directly; instead it generates a PDF for it. The problem is that the image is in landscape mode, and I need it in portrait mode. Neither **okular** nor **qpdf** seems to have a "rotate" facility.  Is there a simple way to rotate that image so that I can print it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to rotate that image so that I can print it?

**Solution #1**

You can use use `pdftk`  a powerful command line toolkit for working with pdf files, downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center. In terminal:

For rotating clockwise 90°: 
`pdftk input.pdf cat 1-endeast output output.pdf`

For rotating anti-clockwise 90°:
`pdftk input.pdf cat 1-endwest output output.pdf`

[man page for pdftk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk)

There's also a GUI for it `PDF Chain`

**Solution #2**

Open the PDF with the default `Document Viewer`

Select the hamburger menu in `Document Viewer` then use the option ⤵ to `Rotate` the image right (successively, as required)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install pdfmod
```

it is a gui which can rotate and save

https://help.gnome.org/users/pdfmod/
https://help.gnome.org/users/pdfmod/0.9/usage.html.en